# Laravel file not passed but available in Request

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, http-post

I've got strange issue : when i'm sending form(2 fields, 1 file) by POST:
[image: empty file field]

with empty file field (coverImage) it still have file on server side

```
       $input = Request::all();
       $coverImage = null;

       $coverImage = Request::file('coverImage');

       print_r($input);
       die();
```

Any suggestions what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what does  print_r($input); display?

Comment: @Dianna
you can see it's output on screen above

Comment: Can you show me your form?

Comment: @Dianna I didn't have too much time to research, but I believe the previously uploaded file is there (in your result), as a validation feature of the framework, so that if other fields fail the validation, the browser doesn't re-upload the same file over and over again.

Comment: @Vlad the response from Lucian is actually addressed to you. Now I'm not exactly sure how you should deal with this, but you might try flushing the input like $request->flash();. Or $request->flashOnly('coverImage'). Don't know if this works but you might give it a try

Answer (score 0):

> Laravel allows you to keep input from one request during the next request. This feature is particularly useful for re-populating forms after detecting validation errors. However, if you are using Laravel's included validation services, it is unlikely you will need to manually use these methods, as some of Laravel's built-in validation facilities will call them automatically.

So you might try flushing the current input this way:

```
$request->flash();
```

Or if you want to flush only certain fields(coverImage let's say) you can do it like this:

```
$request->flashOnly('coverImage');
```